# Is there any way to host Bugzilla over Windows Azure?

Tags: azure, bugzilla

I am trying to host Bugzilla over windows azure for my organization so that it is possible to access the issues created by us anywhere in the world.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I think it belongs [**here**](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bugzilla can be installed on a Windows OS custom Virtual Machine as well. See https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Win32Install You can use IIS instead of Apache if you'd like although the XML-RPC interface only works with Apache.

Comment: Thanks Wayne. This is useful.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. What you really need is Windows Azure Virtual Machine running Linux OS. As Bugzilla has 3 main components, Apache Web Server, Perl and MySQL and you just need to install these 3 components in your Linux (CentOS/SUSE) based Azure Virtual Machine. Once Bugzilla is installed properly, you would need to configure Apache web server through correct port to made is accessible worldwide over web URL and that's it. Windows OS will work as well if you don't want to use Linux.

Added more:

With Windows Azure Virtual Machines, you can create a Linux based VHD locally and install all your required application on it. Once all is done, you can upload your Linux VHD to Azure and configure the ports properly to make it available as needed. The other option is to choose a Linux or Windows OS image from the gallery and then install applications over RDP (Windows) and over SSH Terminal (Linux).

Here are some helpful links:

- [Creating and Uploading a Virtual Hard Disk that Contains the Linux Operating System](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/common-tasks/upload-a-vhd/)
- [How to Create a Custom Virtual Machine](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/how-to-guides/custom-create-a-vm/)

Comment: Thanks Avkash for replying. My doubt is that since the Windows Azure VMs are stateless Machines, we cannot do a conventional install through RDP. We can install Apache Web Server, Perl and MySQL through Image as well. However, I could not find a way to install bugzilla as storing it to the disk would also be non-persistent.

Can you please specify the steps in detail as I have not been able to find any article related to this.

Comment: You are misunderstanding Windows Azure Cloud Services with Windows Azure Virtual Machines. Windows Azure Virtual Machines are stateful machines and data stored on OS and Data disk is persisted. I have added more data above.